# Need help in understanding Android JNI logcat related to IRT

Tags: java, android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

Using Android JNI , I have created file and writing data with file descriptor.

example :-

```
dest = memalign( BLKSIZE,  sz);
if (dest == NULL) {
    LOGE("Unable to allocate memory");
    return -1;
}
memcpy(dest, bufferIn, sz);

int rc = write(fd, dest, sz);
LOGI("write %d bytes.", rc);

free(dest);
if(rc == -1) {
    LOGI("Error in writing : %d %s\n", errno, strerror(errno));
}
```

Write is successful and I can see data in file. But for each write I am getting log in adb logcat.

```
01-06 12:46:36.831 16292-16806/com.test.example I/io: write 1024 bytes.
01-06 12:46:36.831 16292-16806/com.test.example W/art: Attempt to remove
local handle scope entry from IRT, ignoring.
```

1. what this log mean:- I unable to understand, or what this log mean.

   > /*W/art: Attempt to remove local handle scope entry from IRT, ignoring*/
2. Is it something related to app need to handle.

Answer (score 0):

After browsing android source code which is at 
http://androidxref.com/5.1.1_r6/more/art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc?q=Attempt+to+remove+local+handle+scope+entry+from+IRT

I was trying delete local reference

```
(*env)->DeleteLocalRef(env, jbIn);
```

we don't need to delete local references yourself, once the JNI function returns to Java the references will get GC.

Local references will be discarded by JNI on return from a native method, but this process has nothing to do with Java garbage collection. Usually, we don't need to worry about local references.